# Why does Mongo store my date as a string?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

From Node.js I do

```
var startDate = new Date('2012-06-06');
```

Then I save it using mongodb native.  It is stored as follows

> '2012-06-05T14:00:00.000Z'

Comment: Its the ISO 8601 standard - it simply means that you are in UTC+10 timezone, so 6 June hasn't occurred yet at 0 Longitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is the JSON representation of a date:
new Date('2012-06-06').toJSON();

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB stores dates in UTC and not as strings. Check the BSON specs.

http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

Answer (score 1):

It's just how Dates will be displayed. (I thinks it is some kind of ISO standard code.) Internally it is save in a way more efficient way.