# Convert Simple date(11/26/2018) into date type in node js

Tags: node.js

I am sending date from frontend like below:

> 11/26/2018

Now i want to convert it into **type** Date, So that it can be comparable to any other date.How can i do it in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple:

> mydate = new Date("11/26/2018")

See further info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const initialDate="11/26/2018"
let splited = initialDate.split("/");
let date=new Date(splited[2], splited[1] - 1, splited[0])
```

note that the months are indexed from 0.

Comment: can it be compare with any other date?

Comment: you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/5472362

Comment: and if you want to make things easier there is always moment http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mydate = new Date('11/26/18');

var mydate2 = new Date('11/24/18');

console.log('String Format =',mydate.toDateString());
console.log('ISO Format =', mydate.toISOString());

if (mydate > mydate2) {
    console.log('mydate is greater than mydate2');
}else{
    console.log('mydate is less than mydate2');
}
```

you can also use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: can it be compare into any other date?

Comment: i don't know. But i want to save it in mongodb with field type "Date". And on need i want to compare other dates with this one.

Comment: check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375823/javascript-how-to-save-a-date-in-mongodb-document-in-isodate-format

Comment: @Rajat , check two dates are compared